# Enhanced 'for' over Class

Tags: java, class, for-loop

I have a question regarding Java enhanced 'for' statement:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Is there a possibility to use enhanced 'for' statement over Class? (and not only Object)

Here an example:

```
import java.util.*;

class MyRecord
{
  public String name;

  public MyRecord( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class MyCollection implements Iterable<MyRecord>
{
  private static Vector<MyRecord> vec = new Vector<MyRecord>();

  public Iterator<MyRecord> iterator() {
    return vec.iterator();
  }

  public static void add( MyRecord rec ) {
    vec.add( rec );
  }
}

class Test
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    MyCollection.add( new MyRecord( "first" ) );
    MyCollection.add( new MyRecord( "second" ) );

    for( MyRecord rec : MyCollection ) 
      System.out.println( rec.name );
  }
}
```

I'm getting error in the line with 'for':

```
Test.java: error: cannot find symbol
    for( MyRecord rec : MyCollection )
                        ^
  symbol:   variable MyCollection
```

If possible I would like to avoid creating an instance of class MyCollection.

Comment: You can use the singleton pattern here.

Comment: Is there some reason you won't want to create instance of your class?

Comment: `Vector` - a blast from the past

Answer (score 0):

As it is, you must pass an instance of an object to the `for`. If you want to prevent the creation of multiple instances of `MyCollection`, you can use the singleton pattern.

```
class MyCollection implements Iterable<MyRecord>
{
    private static Vector<MyRecord> vec = new Vector<MyRecord>();

    private static final MyCollection INSTANCE = new MyCollection();

    private MyCollection() { /* Hide the constructor */ }

    public static MyCollection getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Iterator<MyRecord> iterator() {
        return vec.iterator();
    }

    public static void add( MyRecord rec ) {
        vec.add( rec );
    }
}
```

From here, you could modify your loop code to use the singleton instance,

```
for( MyRecord rec : MyCollection.getInstance() ) 
    System.out.println( rec.name );
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution works fine for me:

```
try
{
  for( MyRecord rec : MyCollection.class.newInstance() ) 
    System.out.println( rec.name );
}
catch( Exception e )
{
  System.out.println( e );
}
```